# How can I retrieve a pubmed abstract/full article using author, year, and keywords?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python, so maybe there's an easy solution to this that I've missed. I need to be able to obtain the abstract of an article from PubMed using the article's author, year, and some keywords (specifically, the disease being studied in the article).

I can make function that can obtain the url given author/year and a keyword (a variable called 'morphology'):

```
def print_url(author, morphology):
    url="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term="+author+morphology
    print url
```

which, given print_url("Abdel-Ghaffar+et+al+2010", "Diffuse+large+B-cell+lymphoma") prints a url to the article: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=Abdel-Ghaffar+et+al+2010Diffuse+large+B-cell+lymphoma

(note: I took the original keywords and replaces spaces with pluses in excel, so "Abdel-Ghaffar et al 2010" becomes "Abdel-Ghaffar+et+al+2010" for the sake of the url. I don't doubt this can be done in python, but it was easy enough to do in excel anyway.)

It's also pretty simple to get the html for the page:

```
import urllib2

def print_html(author, morphology):
    url="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term="+"%2C+"+author+morphology
    handler=urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html=handler.read()
    print html

abstract_html = print_html("Abdel-Ghaffar+et+al+2010", "Diffuse+large+B-cell+lymphoma")
```

From there, the way I was planning on doing this was to extract the articles Pubmed ID (PMID) from the html based on characters that come before and after the PMID in the html using the following function:

```
def find_between( s, before, after ):
    try:
        start = s.index( before ) + len( before )
        end = s.index( after, before )
        return s[before:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""
```

and then running running this function on the previously defined variable 'html':

```
print find_between( abstract_html, "pmid=", ";" )
```

Since throughout 'html' the ID occurs between "pmid=" and ";". In the case of my example, it would be "pmid=19905895;id" and the output I want is "19905895". From here I could just use Biopython to get the abstract once I have the PMID. But for some reason the above function doesn't work; I get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index"
And when I try to convert the block of html to a string, the function returns nothing at all. So how exactly can I get the pmid out of the html?

Once I have the PMID I could then just use the following code I found in the answer to another question:

```
from Bio.Entrez import efetch

def print_abstract(pmid):
    handle = efetch(db='pubmed', id=pmid, retmode='text', rettype='abstract')
    print handle.read()
```

Or if anyone knows a less roundabout way I could get the abstract using just the author/year and keywords, that would be great too.

Comment: Well, you don't need to do **any** parsing if you use their API correctly.  Look at the "display settings" dropdown, and choose [PMID List](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=Abdel-Ghaffar+et+al+2010Diffuse+large+B-cell+lymphoma&report=uilist&format=text).  You get a response with just the PMID.

Comment: Well, when I open the url for that page I still don't get text; I get a couple lines of XML I think, with the PMID in there of course. At any rate, I was able to get the PMID out of that pretty easily, as opposed to the many many lines I was getting before, so thanks.